# PHP process form, writing to CSV file from HTML form via POST

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

So I'm trying to write the inputs from my HTML form to a CSV file. I am able to write the contents to a csv file, however the process script is writing to the csv file as an array in the foreach loop. I want the output written once in the file. I tried converting to string via 'implode()' but it didn't seem to work as I just received errors from PHP.

here is my output I'm getting (column D has no output so that's not an issue):

[CSV file where each line output is repeated and one further column is filled, until all items in array are reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2reM.png)

here is my process form:

```
<?php 
$list = array (
$quote = $_POST['quote'],
$source = $_POST['source'],
$dob = $_POST['dob'],
$dod = $_POST['dod'],
$wplink = $_POST['wplink'],
$wpimg = $_POST['wpimg'],
$category = $_POST['category']
);

$fp = fopen('trial.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields[]){
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

thanks!

Comment: You want `foreach ($list as $fields){`, otherwise it is multidimensional. Although `$list` is only 1 item anyway, or are all fields arrays?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
// Input prepared for multiple lines CSV file
$list = array (
    // And other error was here, you defined VARIABLES in your array, not key => value pairs (key name identify the column)
    array(
        "quote" => $_POST['quote'],
        "source" => $_POST['source'],
        "dob" => $_POST['dob'],
        "dod" => $_POST['dod'],
        "wplink" => $_POST['wplink'],
        "wpimg" => $_POST['wpimg'],
        "category" => $_POST['category']
    ),
    array(
        "quote 2",
        "source 2",
        "dob 2",
        "dod 2",
        "wplink 2",
        "wpimg 2",
        "category 2"
    )
);

$fp = fopen('trial.csv', 'w');

// The problem is founded here, an unexpected square brackets in foreach header
foreach ($list as $fields){
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);

?>
```